# javascript external file hides source

Tags: javascript, file, external

i have seen answers to similar questions.  but, not quite what i want to know.  if i make an external javascript file.  then, on the client side, when the client loads the HTML, all they see is a link to the external javascript file.  like this:

```
  <script src="myScript.js"></script>
```

they never see the source code.

i don't get all this talk about obfuscation & minification.  best way is just make an external file.  then, without hacking into the server to download the source, they will only get machine code.

Comment: They get only the client side code. So what?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What are you asking

Comment: The client can read clearly the source in the file that you have linked. That file is actually downloaded to the client computer. There is no machine code here.

Comment: Anyone can see your code in *myScript.js* using a developer tool or just by downloading it from yoursite.com/<relativepath>/myScrypt.js. It is not compiled into machine code before sending.

Comment: Funny how those people that do not have even the most basic clue about how these things work, are always the ones worried most about someone “stealing” their code.

Comment: Dmitry. Is it not possible for them to be able to run the code--access it to load through the html, but not permit anonymous ftp?

Comment: i get it now.  but, someone answered that you can hide the source w/PHP server side produced web pages.  i haven't understood this yet.  but, i have seen this answer a few times.  this would seem the way to hide your scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They can still follow the link to get the file directly.

Just display the source of this (this question) page, you can see

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

but you can still simply open https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js to see the source.

Even obfuscation doesn't provide protection as the source is still accessible to the client and he can de-obfuscate it (although that can be hard, it is not impossible).

And minification is used to reduce file size, so the file loads faster (and thus the page load time is lower).

Answer (score 0):

i get it now. but, someone answered that you can hide the source w/PHP server side produced web pages. i haven't understood this yet. but, i have seen this answer a few times. this would seem the way to hide your scripts.